# Android ViewFlipper ZOrder

Tags: android, animation, viewflipper, z-order

I am attempting to use a view flipper to animate the transition between 2 views. It seems that, by default, the ViewFlipper places the Out animation above the In animation in Z order. Is there a way to get the incoming animation to display over the outgoing animation?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can find this feature in the Android Launcher. Since Android is open source you can just copy and work with it.

Take this code called **DragableSpace**: http://pastebin.com/CgK8TCQS. In your activity you call:

```
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

with:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<de.android.projects.DragableSpace
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/de.android.projects"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
    android:id="@+id/space"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:default_screen="1">
    <include android:id="@+id/left" layout="@layout/left_screen" />
    <include android:id="@+id/center" layout="@layout/initial_screen" />
    <include android:id="@+id/right" layout="@layout/right_screen" />
</de.android.projects.DragableSpace>
```

Like you can see you can define a homescreen for your application using just xml ;)

Define each view (initial, right and left)
 like this:

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/center"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:background="@color/orange">
    <Button android:text="Initial Screen" android:id="@+id/Button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp" android:layout_margin="10dp">
    </Button>
</LinearLayout>
```

For more information check out this question: [Developing an Android Homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467461/developing-an-android-homescreen)

Comment: I ended up going with a similar solution. I just wrote my own objects around a FrameLayout and controller the layering more specifically. Things seem to work well now.