# Swiping side to side to switch layouts?

Tags: android-layout

How can I have a layout were when you swipe your finger to the left it goes to another layout or activity?

-EXAMPLE-

```
 {layout 1}         {layout 2 (default)}
                      User SWIPES left
                           <---

                     [moves to Layout 1]
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I think your example is counter-intuitive (I would expect that the User should swipe right to move to layout 1, unless it's cycling through the layouts), there's a few libraries which provide this functionality, most of which based on the Android Homescreen, which uses the idea of workspaces. See this question:

[Developing an Android Homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467461/developing-an-android-homescreen)