# how to view the layouts while swiping one layout half and another layout half should be visible?

Tags: android

how to view the layouts  while swiping one layout half and another layout half should be visible .how to achieve this task?I have used view flipper and I can view next layout while swiping.But I need to see second half of first layout and first half of second layout.pls give some ideas.As shown in the first screen of the image in the link I need to view my layouts.

Comment: You can use also use ViewGrop for page swiping. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467461/developing-an-android-homescreen

Answer (score 0):

You use the ViewPager for this. It can be used by include the android compatibility library which can be found in your sdk folder as a jar file. It allows to include honeycomb api's to older phones.

The [actionbar sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) project demonstrates the capability of this library.

Comment: actually samples from C:\android-sdk\extras\android\compatibility\v4\samples\ demonstrates it too