# How to move to the next screen while keeping a portion of the current screen android ViewFlipper?

Tags: android, viewflipper

I have two Layouts (screens) within ViewFlipper. Assume first layout width is longer than the second layout width. (Let's say, first layout width is 1000dp and second one has width of 500dp).

I can switch between these two screens easily. At the beginning first screen is fully displayed. When I click a button, second screen will come from right and first screen goes to the left. But I want to keep the second screen and (remember, second screen has less width) a portion of the first screen. That means a half of the first screen disappear. How can I do this?

Comment: did you have already a solution for this question?

Comment: No...:-(
couldn't find any solution for this.So I changed my requirement and did this in another way... Thanks for asking.:-)

Comment: You did it with FrameLayout and animation? I think this can't be done "easily" with ViewFlipper..

Comment: yeah... That's right... I used viewFlipper to switch between layouts.but couldn't find a way to switch half of a screen.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this custom dragable space made by matthieu. I am posting here the link. Put it in a new project otherwise it will create the references to your existing activities. This layout will allow you to drag your view group.

[Developing an Android Homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467461/developing-an-android-homescreen)