# is that possible to change launcher icon for another apps in android

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to change another apps(such as Facebook or whats app) launcher icons through code  is that possible?

I want to change another apps launcher icons through code
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't get to change icons for installed apps. You'll have to create your own custom launcher/homescreen app and then you'll be able to show different icons for installed apps. This may be a lot of work if you only want to show a different icon style. 
Check out these topics if you want to create a custom launcher:

[Developing an Android Homescreen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3467461/developing-an-android-homescreen)

[How can I create a custom home-screen replacement application for Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3666771/how-can-i-create-a-custom-home-screen-replacement-application-for-android)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a durable solution - as in something that will be robust enough to work in the long term

The Android [guidelines](http://developer.android.com/training/articles/security-tips.html) state

> The Android Application Sandbox, which isolates your app data and code execution from other apps.

So changing another apps icon isn't going to be that easy.

You could try writing your own launcher, but again its something exploratory.